# DrRackt adding call and fun to a language in the substitution model-tests wont pass

Tags: racket, eval, substitution

I'm using lang pl for this.
I have implemented the language “ROL”, now I'm trying to extend the language to also support fun and call using the substitution model.
My basic code is down below. With some help here I managed to do soand solve my compilation problems. the broblem I'm having now is with 3 new tests I added to check the 'fun' and 'call'.

here is my code:

```
(define-type RegE
[Reg Bit-List]
[And RegE RegE]
[Or RegE RegE]
[Shl RegE]
[Id Symbol]
[With Symbol RegE RegE]
[Bool Boolean]
[Geq RegE RegE]
[Maj RegE]
[If RegE RegE RegE]
[Fun Symbol RegE]
[Call RegE RegE])


(define-type RES
[RES_Bool Boolean]
[RegV Bit-List]
[FunV Symbol RegE])
```

my subset function

```
(define (subst expr from to)
  (cases expr
    [(Reg g) expr]
    [(Bool g) expr]
    [(And left right)(And (subst left from to)(subst right from to))]
    [(Or left right)(Or (subst left from to)(subst right from to))]
    [(If bool ifBody elseBody) (If (subst bool from to) (subst ifBody from to) (subst elseBody from to))]
    [(Maj left)(Maj (subst left from to))]
    [(Geq left right)(Geq (subst left from to)(subst right from to))]
    [(Shl left)(Shl (subst left from to))]
    [(Id name) (if (eq? name from) to expr)]
    [(With bound-id named-expr bound-body)
           (if (eq? bound-id from)
               expr
               (With bound-id
                     named-expr
               (subst bound-body from to)))]
        [(Call left right) (Call (subst left from to) (subst right from to))]
    [(Fun bound-id bound-body)
         (if (eq? bound-id from)
           expr
           (Fun bound-id (subst bound-body from to)))])
    )
```

my eval function:

```
(: eval : RegE -> RES)
;; evaluates RegE expressions by reducing them to bit-lists
(define (eval expr)
  (cases expr
    [(Reg right) (RegV right)]
    [(Bool b) (RES_Bool b)]
    [(Id name) (error 'eval "free identifier: ~s" name)]
    [(And left right) (reg-arith-op bit-and  (eval left ) (eval right) )]
    [(Or left right) (reg-arith-op bit-or (eval left )  (eval right) )]
    [(Shl E1) (RegV (shift-left (RegV->bit-list (eval E1))))]
    [(Maj E1) (RES_Bool (majority? (RegV->bit-list (eval E1))))]
    [(Geq E1 E2) (RES_Bool (geq-bitlists? (RegV->bit-list (eval E1)) (RegV->bit-list (eval E2))))]
    [(With bound-id named-expr bound-body)
       (eval (subst bound-body
                    bound-id
                    (Reg (RegV->bit-list(eval named-expr)))))]
    [(Fun bound-id bound-body) (FunV bound-id bound-body)]
    [(Call fun-expr arg-expr)
       (let ([fval (eval fun-expr)])
         (cases fval
           [(FunV bound-id bound-body)
            (eval (subst bound-body
                   bound-id
                   arg-expr))]
           [else (error 'eval "`call' expects a function, got: ~s"
                              fval)]))]
    [(If E1 E2 E3) (if (RegV->boolean (eval E1)) (eval E2) (eval E3))]


))
```

And the 3 tests that won't pass:

```
(test (run "{ reg-len = 3
 {with {identity {fun {x} x}}
 {with {foo {fun {x} {or x {1 1 0}}}}
 {call {call identity foo} {0 1 0}}}}}")
 => '(1 1 0))
 (test (run "{ reg-len = 3
 {with {x {0 0 1}}
 {with {f {fun {y} {and x y}}}
 {with {x {0 0 0}}
 {call f {1 1 1}}}}}}")
 => '(0 0 1))
(test (run "{ reg-len = 4
 {with {foo {fun {z} {if {maj? z} z {shl z}}}}
 {call foo {if {maj? {0 0 1 1}} {shl {1 0 1 1}} {1 1 0 1}}}}}")
 => '(0 1 1 1))
```

I'm getting the error:

```
RegV->bit-list: Given wrong type of RES (FunV x (Id x))
```

And here is my RegV->bit-list function:

```
(: RegV->bit-list : RES -> Bit-List)
;; extract a bit-list from RES type
(define (RegV->bit-list r)
  (cases r
    [(RegV bl) bl]
    [else (error 'RegV->bit-list "Given wrong type of RES ~s" r)]
    )
  )
```

and my RegV->boolean which have the same principle:

```
(: RegV->boolean : RES -> Boolean)
;; extract a boolean from RES type
(define(RegV->boolean res)
  (cases res
    [(RES_Bool b) b]
    [else (error 'RegV->boolean "Given wrong type of RES ~s" res)]))
```

These two functions used to be:

```
(: RegV->bit-list : RES -> Bit-List)
;; extract a bit-list from RES type
(define(RegV->bit-list rest)
  (cases rest
    [(RES_Bool b) (error 'RegV->bit-list "Given wrong type of RES")]
    [(RegV bits) bits]))

(: RegV->boolean : RES -> Boolean)
;; extract a boolean from RES type
(define(RegV->boolean res)
  (cases res
    [(RES_Bool b) b]
    [(RegV bits) (error 'RegV->bit-list "Given wrong type of RES")]))
```

but then I changed it because I was  getting errors..
Any help would be appriciated...

Answer (score 0):

An idea to help you find the bugs.

Make `eval` print `expr` upon entry:

```
(define (eval expr)
  (display "eval: ") (displayln expr)
  (cases 
     ...))
```

The evaluate one of the three offending expressions.
Check which step in the evaluation that goes wrong.

If you need more detail, make `subst` print its arguments too.